# Azure CLI - Automation account replace-content is breaking on new line

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli

I've got a very frustrating situation using the Azure CLI and attempting to replace the content of an Automation Account.

I am attempting to update it via a Azure DevOps pipeline AzureCLI@2 task. This is the script line i am calling

```
az automation runbook replace-content --debug --automation-account-name "${{ parameters.automationAccountName }}" --resource-group "${{ parameters.resourceGroup }}" --name "Schedule Summary" --content "`@temp.txt"
```

The issue i am having is the automation account runbook is updated, but the text is truncated. The contents of temp.txt is this -

```
Param(
    [string]$resourceGroup ='',
    [string]$UAMI ='',
    [string]$serverInstance ='',
```

But the script that ends up in the runbook is simply

```
Param(
```

Its clearly breaking on CRLF but i can't figure out how to fix it. If i remove all CRLF then it appears as one line and the script then doesn't run.

I can tell where the problem is? Is the AzureCLI, powershell? or the devops task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run the script in windows hosted agent and reproduce your issue.Its clearly breaking on CRLF. Because windows can't identify the CRLF. You should run the script in Linux agent.

**breaking on CRLF based on windows agent**
[image: RESULT]

**alter to linux agent in pipeline**

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-22.04
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tried in my environment by adding Devops CLI extension in Azure bash and it worked for me successfully with the same parameters as yours.

I created a PS file in Az cloud itself and saved with the `.ps1 extension` as set the runbook type to PowerShell and updated the script as follows:

```bash
az automation runbook replace-content --content "@runbook.ps1" --automation-account-name "xxxxautomation" --name "xxxxrunbook" --resource-group "xxxxRG"
```

***vi*** `runbook.ps1`:

[image]

***Content replacement done in runbook***:

[image]

***If still the issue persists***: In Azure DevOps, call a webhook with parameters and then start a runbook that imports the Azure DevOps runbooks.

But when you are dealing with Azure DevOps, I suggest you create or update runbooks via [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/automation/runbook/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP) instead of PowerShell modules which is efficient.